# Is it possible to integrate $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n}}{x+5} dx + \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5} dx$? If so, how?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

Maybe there is some method I am forgetting, but I do not remember how to solve this (if it is even solvable).
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n}}{x+5} dx + \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5} dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is solvable, although the answer is ugly: 
\begin{align*}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+1)}{x+5}dx&=\int_0^1x^{n-1}\bigg(1-\frac 4{x+5}\bigg)dx\\
&=\frac1n-4\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5}dx\\
&=\frac1n-4\int_5^6 \frac{(u-5)^{n-1}}{u}du\\
&=\frac1n-4\int_5^6\frac1u\bigg(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}r u^{n-r-1}(-5)^r \bigg)du\\
&=\frac1n-4\int_5^6 \sum_{r=0}^{n-2}\binom {n-1}ru^{n-r-2}(-5)^r +\frac{(-5)^{n-1}}{u}du\\
&=\frac1n-4\sum_{r=0}^{n-2}\binom {n-1}r\frac{(-5)^r (6^{n-r-1}-5^{n-r-1})}{n-r-1}-4(-5)^{n-1}\log\frac 65.\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

If you want a "closed-form" version without the summation, it can be written as

$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{4}{5}\Phi\left(-\frac{1}{5},1,n\right)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch Phi function](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LerchPhi).

This comes from the series

$$\frac{1}{x+5} = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{x}{5}\right)^k $$

so that $$\eqalign{\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5}\; dx &= \frac{1}{5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^k \int_0^1 x^{n+k}\; dx = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k+1} \left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^k \cr &= \frac{1}{n} - \Phi\left(-\frac{1}{5},1,n\right)}$$
and similarly
$$ \eqalign{\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5} \; dx &= \frac{1}{5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k}  \left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^k \cr & = \frac{\Phi\left(-\frac{1}{5},1,n\right)}{5}}$$

Comment: Arguably, I'd prefer this version for being more concise, even if it is in some sense less "simple" or not "elementary". One of the real tricks with maths is learning not to become too stuck on the idea that there is only one "right" _representation_ of a problem and/or answer, or that a particular type of representation is _always_ better than another type.

Answer (score 1):

Using special functions, we also could use the gaussian hypergeometric function and get for
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+1)}{x+5}\,dx$$

$$I_n=\frac{n \Big(\, _2F_1\left(1,n;n+1;-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\,_2F_1\left(1,n+1;n+2;-\frac{1}{5}\right)\Big)+\,
   _2F_1\left(1,n;n+1;-\frac{1}{5}\right)}{5 n (n+1)}$$